# Show a Selection When a Selection Option is Picked

Tags: javascript, selection, hidden

Here's the Thing: If I Select:

1. "Africa", Africa Selection will be Shown, the Rest will be Hidden.
2. "America", America Selection will be Shown, the Rest will be Hidden.
3. "Asia", Asia Selection will be Shown, the Rest will be Hidden.
   and So On.

   ```
   <select name="continent" id="continent" size="1">
       <option value="Pick a Continent">Pick a Continent First.</option>
       <option value="Africa" class="africa">Africa</option>
       <option value="America" class="america">America</option>
       <option value="Asia" class="asia">Asia</option>
       <option value="Europe" class="europe">Europe</option>
       <option value="Oceania and Pacific" class="oceana">Oceania and Pacific</option>
   </select>
       <select name="Africa" id="africa" size="1">
       <option value="Pick a Sub-Region.">Pick a Sub-Region.</option>
       <option value="North Africa">North Africa</option>
       <option value="East Africa">East Africa</option>
       <option value="Central Africa">Central Africa</option>
       <option value="West Africa">West Africa</option>
       <option value="Southern Africa">Southern Africa</option>
   </select>
   <select name="America" id="america" size="1">
       <option value="Pick a Sub-Region.">Pick a Sub-Region.</option>
       <option value="North America">North America</option>
       <option value="Central America">Central America</option>
       <option value="South America">South America</option>
   </select>
   ```

CSS and/or JavaScript on JSFiddle would Do. Thank You.

EDIT: Here's What I Did on JavaScript (So Far)

```
function hide(africa){
    document.getElementById('africa');
    africa.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function show(africa){
    document.getElementById('africa');
    africa.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function hide(america){
    document.getElementById('america');
    america.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function show(america){
    document.getElementById('america');
    america.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Comment: Showing your effort and what you have tried, would Do. Thank You.

Comment: Now that's better and we are going somewhere. See, you have coded actions fine, but when are those actions going to fire? You need to bind event on the continent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function hide(elem){
       //hide all sub regions
   for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('subRegion').length; i++){ 
    document.getElementsByClassName('subRegion')[i].style.display = 'none';
   }
   
   var sub = elem.value.toLowerCase(); 
   document.getElementById(sub).style.display = 'inline';
   
  }
```

```css
 .subRegion{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
</head>

<body>
 <FORM>
   <select name="continent" id="continent" size="1" onchange="hide(this)">
   <option value="Pick a Continent">Pick a Continent First.</option>
   <option value="Africa" class="africa">Africa</option>
   <option value="America" class="america">America</option>
   <option value="Asia" class="asia">Asia</option>
   <option value="Europe" class="europe">Europe</option>
   <option value="Oceania and Pacific" class="oceana">Oceania and Pacific</option>
  </select>
   <select name="Africa" id="africa" size="1" class="subRegion">
   <option value="Pick a Sub-Region.">Pick a Sub-Region.</option>
   <option value="North Africa">North Africa</option>
   <option value="East Africa">East Africa</option>
   <option value="Central Africa">Central Africa</option>
   <option value="West Africa">West Africa</option>
   <option value="Southern Africa">Southern Africa</option>
  </select>
  <select name="America" id="america" size="1" class="subRegion">
   <option value="Pick a Sub-Region.">Pick a Sub-Region.</option>
   <option value="North America">North America</option>
   <option value="Central America">Central America</option>
   <option value="South America">South America</option>
  </select>
 
 </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It Works for Me. I'll Upload the Site When Everything's Ready. Thank You for Reminding Me Back to the Basics of JavaScript, too.

Comment: By the Way, I Hope You Could Help Me with This:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/MaryWilliameTaraneeChristine/151fnvpy/1/)

The Countries of the Corresponding Regions Should Appear when a Certain Region is Selected.

For Example: Southeast Asian Countries are Brunei, Cambodia, etc.

Comment: you have function hide1 and hide2 that do the same thing. you need an onchange function for the subregion.  I will create a new fiddle link and send it to you

Comment: I Hope I Got Some Right: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MaryWilliameTaraneeChristine/qena8rh2/)

Comment: the example in this link works but make sure you change the Framework & Extensions sidebar options to "No wrap - in <head>".  For some reason it's not saving http://jsfiddle.net/byz9vbj7/4/

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do using Jquery

HTML goes this way

```
<select name="continent" id="continent" size="1">
    <option value="Pick a Continent">Pick a Continent First.</option>
    <option value="Africa" class="africa">Africa</option>
    <option value="America" class="america">America</option>
    <option value="Asia" class="asia">Asia</option>
    <option value="Europe" class="europe">Europe</option>
    <option value="Oceania and Pacific" class="oceana">Oceania and Pacific</option>
</select>
<select name="Africa" id="africa" size="1" class="subselect">
    <option value="Pick a Sub-Region.">Pick a Sub-Region.</option>
    <option value="North Africa">North Africa</option>
    <option value="East Africa">East Africa</option>
    <option value="Central Africa">Central Africa</option>
    <option value="West Africa">West Africa</option>
    <option value="Southern Africa">Southern Africa</option>
</select>
<select name="America" id="america" size="1" class="subselect">
    <option value="Pick a Sub-Region.">Pick a Sub-Region.</option>
    <option value="North America">North America</option>
    <option value="Central America">Central America</option>
    <option value="South America">South America</option>
</select>
```

Your css [i have added class subselect for your other select boxes]

```
.subselect{
    display:none;
}
```

And then the JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#continent').on('change',function(){            //to capture when option is selected
      var data= $('#continent option:selected').val(); //get the value of selected option
      var selectbox="select[name='"+data+"']";         //finding the respective subselect
        $(selectbox).show();                           //showing the select box required
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle for your reference [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nephilim11/wL7eeokq/) check it out

And if you want to hide the previous select if user selects a new Continent then use this js

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#continent').on('change',function(){            //to capture when option is selected
         $('.subselect').css('display','none');
         var data= $('#continent option:selected').val(); //get the value of selected option
          var selectbox="select[name='"+data+"']";         //finding the respective subselect
            $(selectbox).show();                           //showing the select box required
        });
    });
```

Comment: The Op has not tagged the question as `jQuery`. Op is using plain old `Javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to bind the event to the `continent` select.

```js
document.getElementById("continent").addEventListener("change", showhide);

function showhide() {
  var sel = document.getElementById("continent").value;
  if (sel == 'Africa') {
    document.getElementById('africa').style.display = 'inline-block';
    document.getElementById('america').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('america').style.display = 'inline-block';
    document.getElementById('africa').style.display = 'none';
  }
  
}
```

```css
#africa, #america {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="continent" id="continent" size="1">
    <option value="Pick a Continent">Pick a Continent First.</option>
    <option value="Africa" class="africa">Africa</option>
    <option value="America" class="america">America</option>
    <option value="Asia" class="asia">Asia</option>
    <option value="Europe" class="europe">Europe</option>
    <option value="Oceania and Pacific" class="oceana">Oceania and Pacific</option>
</select>
<select name="Africa" id="africa" size="1">
    <option value="Pick a Sub-Region.">Pick a Sub-Region.</option>
    <option value="North Africa">North Africa</option>
    <option value="East Africa">East Africa</option>
    <option value="Central Africa">Central Africa</option>
    <option value="West Africa">West Africa</option>
    <option value="Southern Africa">Southern Africa</option>
</select>
<select name="America" id="america" size="1">
    <option value="Pick a Sub-Region.">Pick a Sub-Region.</option>
    <option value="North America">North America</option>
    <option value="Central America">Central America</option>
    <option value="South America">South America</option>
</select>
```